# Centering a TextView while keeping it to the right of a button?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm pretty sure I've done this before, but I've forgotten how.

Here's the problem:
I've got a button and a textview, and I want the textview to be centered, while the button is on the left side.

No problem? Just put them in a relativelayout, make the textview centerinparent, and the button alignparentleft.

But now I'm going to dynamically change the text, so it can potentially be written on top of the button! I'll just add toRightOf="@id/button" on the textview. No, now it's no longer centered.

I wish I could provide a screenshot, but it seems the computer is out of memory and can't do that.

<strike>Here's some code: http://pastebin.com/3N70Vjre (Since I can't paste xml...?)</strike>

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/leftbutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="text!"
                />
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toptext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/leftbutton"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Text!"
                android:singleLine="true"
                />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you clarify if you are talking about horizontal or vertical centering? Which one is working and which one is not?

Comment: I'm talking about horizontal centering. Vertical centering within the relativelayout is working just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (unfortunately I'm at work so can't jump into Eclipse to get you some code) -

- Change the layout_width of the TextView to fill_parent.
- Set the gravity of the TextView to center (so the text centers inside the TextView)
- Set the layout_weight of the Button to 1 and the layout_weight of the TextView to 2. Note that you may have to fudge with these numbers to get the layout you're looking for.

This should center the text of the TextView after the Button, though it will not center the TextView itself. You can accomplish that by replacing the TextView with a container (Linear/Relative Layout) and doing the same method as above on the Layout instead of the TextView. You would then put your TextView inside the container and set the container's gravity to "center".

Hope this helps point you in the right direction :)

Comment: Thanks. I managed to get it half-working, and you were closest to my solution so I'm gonna award you with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the TextView first, then aligning the button to the left of the text view. Keep in mind you may run into issues if the TextView becomes too wide.

EDIT: I see, so you're trying to do something sort of like the iPhone's header with back/next buttons (similar anyway). Try this modification. I still believe you're going to run into issues if the TextView gets large enough to hit the Button, though.

```
  <RelativeLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/header"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      >
      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/toptext"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textColor="@android:color/white"
          android:layout_alignParentCenter="true"
          android:textSize="16sp"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:text="Text!"
          android:singleLine="true"
          />
      <Button
          android:id="@+id/leftbutton"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:text="text!"
          />        
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Try this FrameLayout instead. This may do more what you're expecting:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toptext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Text!"
        android:singleLine="true"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/leftbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text!"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: That puts the button right next to the textview and centers them both. Now, if I set the button's alignParentLeft="true", the button stretches until it reaches the textview. And if the textview becomes too wide, it pushes the button out. Just reversed my problem, basically :P

Comment: Can you explain why you're trying to do this, exactly? Seems like you're going to run into issues with this type of layout regardless of whether you get this instance working.

Comment: Because this: http://img801.imageshack.us/img801/4372/tablelayout.png minus the right button in my layout, looks better than having the textview mashed right next to the button and using padding or margins to push it away.

Comment: I could make a button or any other type of view and align that to the right, make it invisible and make the textview sit between those. But that seems a little dumb.

Comment: Added one more thing. Try the FrameLayout instead.

Comment: Yeah, something sort of like the iPhone's header with a back-button. I tried your updated suggestion, and you're right, the text now hides behind the button if it gets too wide (and it will most certainly get too wide). I can't believe this is so hard :P Thanks for trying :)

Comment: So what exactly do you want it to do if it DOES get too wide?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (pseudo-code):

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <Button>
  <LinearLayout toLeftOf="toptext" type="horizontal">
    <TextView gravity="center">
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You might have to have the LinearLayout as width="fill_parent". Not sure if that will work nor not. You can subsequently try some of the things listed here: http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/14/how-to-position-views-properly-in-layouts/

Comment: That doesn't work either. And if it did, the textview would be centered horizontally inside of the Linearlayout, not inside the Relativelayout. Centered + the width of the button, that is. Maybe there's a way to get the width of the button and use that to subtract from the left margin of the textview? :\

Comment: Not if the width was fill_parent. The LinearLayout would fill the rest of the horizontal space and center the TextView inside of it.

Comment: Yes, but it would only be able to fill the part that did not contain the button.